# Profanities in Django comments

Tags: python, django, nlp

Since Django doesn't handle filtering profanities - does anyone have any suggestions on an easy way to implement some sort of natural language processing / filtering of profanities in django?

Answer (score 7):

Django does handle filtering profanities.

From https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#profanities-list:

> PROFANITIES_LIST
>
> Default: () (Empty tuple)
>
> A tuple of profanities, as strings, that will be forbidden in comments when
> `COMMENTS_ALLOW_PROFANITIES` is `False`.

That said you'll still need to populate that list. [Some](https://superuser.com/questions/37597/where-do-you-find-a-good-list-of-banned-words) [links](http://www.bannedwordlist.com/) [to](http://www.infochimps.com/datasets/list-of-dirty-obscene-banned-and-otherwise-unacceptable-words) [get](http://urbanoalvarez.es/blog/2008/04/04/bad-words-list/) [started](http://www.mdaniels.com/profanity/).

I would also familiarize yourself with the [Scunthorpe problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem).

Comment: Note: it's been mentioned since 1.3 that PROFANITIES_LIST should be deprecated. I believe both Adrian Holovaty and Daniel Greenberg mentioned in recent talks that this was planned for 1.5. It's still in master branch right now, but I'd assume (hope) it's about to disappear.

Comment: +1 Yea i personally think having a profanities list is a waste of time, but was correcting the question since Django does have basic handling. Here's a link to the release note about changing the built in list to be empty - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/releases/1.3/#no-more-naughty-words

Comment: +1 for the Scunthorpe problem. @Tom I believe what was deprecated was the list contents - as you see it now defaults to an empty tuple, but used to be populated with just four rather random insults.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Deprecating the list contents was the first step.  The plan (at least as I understand it) is for the setting to be properly removed.

Comment: @TomChristie what makes you think that is the next step? There's no mention of that in the Django Deprecation Timeline, which goes up to 2.0 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/deprecation/

Comment: I believe it's been mentioned in passing.  The closest I can get is this gist of the Adrian's DjangoCon 2012 talk - https://gist.github.com/3643761.  Anyway, actions not words, so... [ticket raised](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18965#ticket), I'll follow up with a pull req if it is due to disappear.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I say... don't bother. If you create better filters, they will simply type it differently...

But, here's a simple example:

```
import re
bad_words = ['spam', 'eggs']
# The \b gives a word boundary so you don't have the Scunthorpe problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem
pattern = re.compile(
    r'\b(%s)\b' % '|'.join(bad_words),
    re.IGNORECASE,
)

some_text = 'This text contains some profane words like spam and eggs. But it wont match spammy stuff.'
print some_text
# This text contains some profane words like spam and eggs. But it wont match spammy stuff.

clean_text = pattern.sub('XXX', some_text)
print clean_text
# This text contains some profane words like XXX and XXX. But it wont match spammy stuff.
```

Comment: Yahoo makes itself look stupid by considering "BS" profane and censoring posts on Bachelor of Science degrees.  Unless you're going to do enough NLP to understand context, be sure your list of profanities is unambiguous.